# Regex how to match the string even if I don't know where/if it contains additional character

Tags: regex

I have simple regex to match First name and Last name:

```
(\b(ALICE)([A-Z ]*){0,1}(SMITH))
```

String to match

```
HELLO  ALICE WILLIAMS SMITH WORLD
```

**Everything works fine!**

But what can I do if I have such strings too (When I do **NOT** know where will be the space/space**s** in the first name):

```
  HELLO  A LICE WILLIAMS SMITH WORLD
  HELLO  ALI CE WILLIAMS SMITH WORLD
```

I think I have optional *\s characters like this:

```
(ALICE) --> (A*\sL*\sI*\sC*\sE)
```

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to match “a string” or are you trying to match “First name and Last name” because [those are two very different things](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: Usually, people just insert `\s?` in between the letters of the searched word.

Comment: \s is good point. I've found it 3 min ago. thanks!

Comment: @grep are you using a particular language?  Not all regex engines are created equal.

Answer (score 0):

We can use *\s optional characters:

```
(\b(A\s*L\s*I\s*C\s*E)([A-Z ]*){0,1}(SMITH))
```

Comment: You don't care about word boundaries at the end of ALICE nor around SMITH?

Comment: `(\bA\s*L\s*I\s*C\s*E\b).*?(\bSMITH\b)` would be more robust in my opinion.

Comment: If you precede it with `(?i)` it will not be case sensitive.

Comment: @WJS I don't believe that is universal. OP did not specify a programming language and we don't know if case-insensitivity is desirable anyways.

Comment: @WJS For one it's not supported in Javascript

Comment: Thanks! You are great!